# Search JSON tree based on <select> option

Tags: jquery, json, csv, select

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
            "State": "Alabama",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 1",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Alabama",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 2",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Alabama",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 3",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
    {
            "State": "Alaska",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 1",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Alaska",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 2",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Alaska",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 3",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Arkansas",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 1",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Arkansas",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 2",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        },
        {
            "State": "Arkansas",
            "Specialty": "Specialty 3",
            "Cat1": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat2": "$xxx,xxx",
            "Cat3": "$xxx,xxx"
        }
]
```

I want to use this JSON file display the 3 category values, based on 2 user select dropdowns (State and specialty). This JSON file will be edited somewhat frequently via CSV and converted to JSON which will be formatted in this way which is the biggest obstacle I have in trying to complete this. I can search JSON trees in other formats, but this one has given me some issues. Any idea what the easiest way to go about this is?

Comment: rewerite it to `data[<state>][<speciality>] = {}` ... will be easy to select then.

Comment: This answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7364307/2401021

Comment: @FlashThunder As stated above, the converter tool I am using from my CSV file is exporting the JSON in this format. I'm either strapped to using this format for JSON, or coming up with a way to format my CSV so that it can output an more accessible JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not a fan of libraries for every little thing, but when using a large JSON file, perhaps you could use http://defiantjs.com/.

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xQpp8vyO1haLFIXy3JOP?p=preview

Basically you just query JSON like this: `JSON.search(obj, '//*[State="Alabama"]/Specialty');`

If you'll have problems with any specific query, let me know.